# Easy Slider 1.7 - make entire slide clickable

Tags: css, block, href

I'm using the [Easy Slider](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider) on my [home page](http://bit.ly/mhUpk1).

My question is, how can I make each entire slide clickable? Currently only the h3 and p are clickable.

Here is my code:

```
<li id="header1">
    <a href="history/">
        <h3>Championship History</h3>
        <p>Perhaps the most important aspect of Stanford's athletics program is that its success serves to validate the "scholar-athlete" approach to intercollegiate athletics competition. READ MORE &raquo;</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li id="header2">
    <a href="voices-of-champions/">
        <h3>Voices of Champions</h3>
        <p>A rare and exceptional group of individuals, Stanford scholar-athletes deserve to be heard. READ MORE &raquo;</p>
    </a>
</li>
...
```

I've tried switching the `<a>` and `<li>`, but it messes up the slideshow and doesn't show all the slides.

Any help is greatly appreiated :)

Comment: i'll take a look this weekend and will post something if i figure anything out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hack way to do it could be to add onclick events.

I have done this before with my own script (http://magazine.missouristate.edu, the top area with the images), but I can't remember doing it with Easy Slider.

Comment: thanks for your reply. How exactly did you do this on your page?

Comment: If you look at the code of the page there is a script block near the bottom that does most of the magic. Basically what it does is precache the images using javascript then insert the new image behind the current image based on what should be next after which fades out the top image. Then it removes the old one. It does all this based on the tags and IDs on the html elements. I wrote it a few years ago so it might need some optimizing.

Maybe I should write my own plugin lol.